# Spring Authorization Server and user registration

Tags: spring-security

I am looking at using the new Spring Authorization Server. I have got the samples working and seen how the test users are validated but have a question about where the user registration function should be added.

Should this be added to the authorization server or another separate service (e.g. userprofile)? If it's the latter, I assume I would have to connect the auth server to the user database.

Ideally, I would like users to click a login button, they are taken to the login page on the auth server. If they don't have an account, they create one and then they are taken back to the app with a token.

I was looking at the [openid connect initiating user registration spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-prompt-create-1_0.html) but don't think it has been implemented.

Answer (score -1):

> According to my experience User registration functionality should be
> belonged to the authorization server. When client wants to access
> Users' protected resources, the request must be made on behalf of the
> User if exist. New User should be registered with Authorization Server
> if not exist.

- User Registration
- User Authentication
- Provide Access Token
- User Authorization by Verified Token

That's mean your are right:

"Users to click a login button, they are taken to the login page on the auth server. If they don't have an account, they create one and then they are taken back to the app with a token."

Hope you understood the concept.